# Ubuntu 14.04 : Cannot access internet via terminal

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless, iptables

I am able to connect to both wired and wireless networks and able to browse via a browser. So I don't think there's any network issue.

However I cannot run any internet based command from my terminal
even a `sudo apt-get update` 
command gets stuck showing

```
`0% [Connecting to 7.1.1.12 (7.1.1.12)] [Connecting to 7.1.1.12 (7.1.1.12)]`
```

and get stuck there.

I tried doing `sudo iptables -F` after following another answer but to no good.

Please help me with this.

1. Output of `ping google.com`

   ```
   PING google.com (216.58.220.14) 56(84) bytes of data.<b>    
   64 bytes from bom05s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.220.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=1.91 ms
   64 bytes from bom05s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.220.14): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=2.04 ms
   64 bytes from bom05s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.220.14): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=1.73 ms
   64 bytes from bom05s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.220.14): icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=1.75 ms
   ```
2. Output of `ping 8.8.8.8`

   ```
   PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=1.62 ms
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=5.49 ms    
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=1.39 ms    
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=1.39 ms    
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=1.46 ms    
   64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=1.44 ms
   ```
3. Output of `env | grep -i proxy`

   ```
   http_proxy=http:// 7.1.1.12:3128/
   ftp_proxy=ftp:// 7.1.1.12:3128/
   socks_proxy=socks:// 7.1.1.12:3128/
   https_proxy=https:// 7.1.1.12:3128/
   ```

Comment: Are you using a proxy server in your GUI applications that you haven't told the command-line applications about?

Comment: No proxies in use. The browsers are using the default configurations only.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be connecting to US Department of Defence? They don't seem to have any web server on that address, so I am suspecting it isn't legit. Somebody may have been forging some DNS replies.

Comment: I am a naive user and have no clue of what's happening to be honest. I haven't changed any settings on my part. Could you tell me how to reset the whole thing ?

Comment: what are you **trying** to do? ... maybe "internet based command" is not for naïve users

Comment: I state one example in the question itself:
`sudo apt-get update` after which I want to install a package

Comment: And yes, I faced the same with `git push origin master` so I am sure something has gone wrong but I am not able to solve it after Google search. Hoping someone here would point me to the solution

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and post the output of i) `ping google.com` ii) `ping 8.8.8.8`; iii) `env | grep -i proxy`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `apt-get` command is finding those `http_proxy` entries and attempting to connect to the internet through them.  In this case, it is an IP address belonging to the [Department of Defense](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/7.1.1.12), and the `:3128` is indicating Squid.

Either you do work for the DoD - in which case you should not be posting this information on a public forum, this should be going through your department admin.

Or you accidentally added those entries there.  Check your `/etc/environment` file for those entries and comment them out.  If it isn't in `/etc/environment`, have a look at your `~/.profile` file as well; same deal, just comment them out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i see a space into the URL, just before the IP addresses. Please remove those spaces from those *proxy env variables, and if that doesn't work, please try to unset it.

To set it correctly:
export http_proxy=http://7.1.1.12:3128/

To unset it:
unset http_proxy

Edit: Just repeat it for all *proxy variables